# Can you help me with layouts on react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

How to creat [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqSOH.jpg) layout on react native? Can you provide me example? I dont understand how to creat it, because here very poor css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://rnplay.org/apps/W0vWoQ) you go. This should give you a good idea on how to use styling in React Native. The sample code is below as well:

https://rnplay.org/apps/W0vWoQ

One of the main concepts is [Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) for layout, so I would take a look at that. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html#content) is an overall overview of styling.

```
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.one}><Text style={styles.logo}>Text Logo</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.two}></View>
        <View style={styles.three}>
            <Text>Some Texxt</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,    
  },
  logo: {
    color: 'white'
  },  
    one: {
        flex:2,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
 two: {
        flex:7,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
    three: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopWidth:4,

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question: How to create button with 100% width?

Comment: There are really a lot of different ways to do it, and many of them depend on the state of the container they are in. Anyway, I've edited the above example and added a full width button that works with the way the above is set up.